# vertical alignment of sum with substack

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, substack

Sums and products are usually centred vertically. However, I find the following looks a bit silly, with the big vertical space above the sum expression:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \max_{y\in Y} \left\{ \sum_{\substack{x\in X\colon \\ f(x) = y}} g(x,y) \right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a reasonable way to resolve this, or should I just live with the weird extra space? (I suppose this is a question about the proper way to typeset this sort of thing, as well as a technical question about LaTeX.)

Comment: I need exactly a solution to this problem without getting rid of the `\left\{` bracket. Is there a way to vertically center the whole term (including the substack content)?

Comment: @johk95 it might be worth asking a separate question. (This particular stack exchange is pretty lenient about duplicates in my experience - as long as you include the specifics of your case and make it clear that you're asking about vertically centring the whole term it should be considered a different question)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you replace the auto-sizing instructions `\left` and `\right` with `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`, respectively. Better yet, consider *not* using curly braces for the expression at hand. "Snugging up" the  elements in the math list via `\smashoperator` directive -- see the third term below -- may also be a good idea.

A separate issue: Using `\colon` in a `\substack` would appear to cause some unfortunate spacing issues -- see the first two terms below. Using `{:}` instead of `\colon` -- see the third term below -- gets around the spacing issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  &\max_{y\in Y} 
  \left\{ 
     \sum_{\substack{x\in X\colon \\ f(x) = y}} g(x,y) 
  \right\}  \\[2\jot]
  &\max_{y\in Y} 
  \Bigl\{ 
     \sum_{\substack{x\in X\colon \\ f(x) = y}} g(x,y) 
  \Bigr\}  \\[\jot]
  &\max_{y\in Y} 
     \smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{x\in X{:} \\ f(x) = y}}} g(x,y) 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```